# DotNetRDF writing to RDF Exception errors

Tags: c#, rdf, dotnetrdf

How do I debug/validate my SKOS / RDF?
What tools are available on Windows 10?

I've been building SKOS /RDF using DotNetRDF

The Problem is:
When I try to output to a file I can save to .ttl but get `"System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The URI is empty.'` when saving to .rdf

I have no idea how to find this empty URI opening it in a txt editor isn't helpful

```
     //  This Works
    CompressingTurtleWriter ttlwriter = new CompressingTurtleWriter();
    ttlwriter.Save(g, @"C:\Temp\DotNetRDFTestG.ttl");

    //  this errors
    RdfXmlWriter rdfxmlwriter = new RdfXmlWriter();
    rdfxmlwriter.Save(g, @"C:\Temp\MydotNetRdf.rdf");
```

I don't know if this is related but:

I can add the .ttl file to Apache Jena Fuseki but when I try and view it in SKOSMOS I get the `Undefined index: http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept` in the Apache error log.

Are there any tutorials that include DotNETRDF, Apache Jena Fuseki, and SKOSMOS?